# Table hint on linked server query

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

We have a DB2 database in AS400. Added a linked server, all went well, however occasionally the table is locked, even when we doing some select queries. Thinking about table hint in SQL Server, does the linked server query (e.g. select * from ...) support table hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubtful, but I don't know for sure.

Are you using openquery() , or 4 part names?

A query using 4 part names like so:

```
select * from LNKSVRNAME.IBMINAME.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE where somecolumn = '00335';
```

Pulls back all the rows from `MYTABLE` and does the `WHERE` filtering on MS SQL Server.

In contrast, using openquery() like so:

```
select * from openquery(LNKSVRNAME, 'select * from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE where somecolumn = ''00335''');
```

Sends the query to the IBM i, and only the matching rows from MYTABLE are pulled back into MS SQL Server.

If the table is being locked exclusively, there's not much you can do.  However, if you're running into row locks.  You may want to look at the following DB2 for IBM i clauses

- `FOR READ ONLY`
- `SKIP LOCKED DATA` or `USE CURRENTLY COMMITTED` or `WAIT FOR OUTCOME`

So something like this:

```
select * from openquery(LNKSVRNAME, 'select * from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE where somecolumn = ''00335'' FOR READ ONLY USE CURRENTLY COMMITTED');
```

**Note**  If you are actually talking to an AS/400, `FOR READ ONLY` is all you'll have available.  But if you're talking to a relatively recent IBM POWER System running a relatively recent version of IBM i, then the `concurrent-access-resolution` clauses I've shown should be available.